# the meaning of "take on" translation confusing

Tags: meaning, phrases

I know ''take on'' has the meaning of "undertake"  ,
however what make me confused is that the translation is too flexible.
it can be translated to "undertake","begin to do","to accept /to address" and etc.

so I am really confused. It has so much translation? what can i do??

Comment: Phrasal verbs can have more than one meaning. This is one such case.

Comment: @Gustavson i know it has other meaning like hire ,or complete but what i am confused is that when it means undertake it can also have many translation

Answer (score 1):

Some words have broad fields of meaning. To determine precisely what is meant when such words are used requires looking at context. You have given no context. Presumably, you are trying to translate FROM English to some other language. I doubt that this site can advise on other languages. It certainly cannot when the other language is unknown.

Generally, "take on" is used to mean to start or to attempt a difficult task. One might say "I am taking on a translation of the Book of the Dead into a set of a villanelles" to indicate that a villanelle is a demanding type of poem. Few able-bodied people would say "I am taking on a trip to the corner store."

Comment: what is the meaning of demanding type of poem

Comment: if it is not a difficult task, just some usual work. For example,,, I don't want to take on any more tasks because I am really tireosmd recently, Does this sentence ,right? and the most important pohrint that I am confused about is that does this phrase indicate "undertake the responsibility"?

Comment: and I have seen such a sentence: we don't take on new clients now. I think this kind of usage is rare

Comment: "take on new clients" means "accept new clients"; "I don't want to take on any more tasks because I'm tired" means "undertake". I don't know what "pohrint" is supposed to be and I am assuming "tireosmd" is "tired". "take on new clients" is very common.

Comment: so it  all depends on the content. I take on the new task and I am confident to finish it. it means "commit myself to it" ? or "undertake"?

Comment: and does" take on" indicate "begin to"?

Comment: @rene As has been explained now several times, "take on" has multiple meanings. It may mean nothing more than "start" or "accept." And it cam mean to "undertake" or "attempt," particularly something challenging. Which meaning it has depends on context. And villanelles are very hard to write in English. The only good one I can recall is "Do Not Go Gentle into that Good Night."

Comment: @Jeff Morrow so the last question.can it mean "begin to undertake "or the meaning should be separated to "began "and "undertake" ---- I cannot combine "begin" and" undertake " into one meaning

Comment: "Accept" and "begin" do not mean the same thing. There is no one meaning of "undertake." Merriam Webster for example gives three. The word most generally is used to mean to "commit to attempt" or at least "plan to attempt" a task or duty, frequently a task of some difficulty or a duty of some responsibility. But it can mean to start or begin a task. What exactly the sense is depends on context.

Comment: start for example take on a new life

Comment: so it cannot mean"undertake"? ife the sentence is we don't want to take on the task .It means undertake or commit to attempt?

Comment: If we do not undertake we do not take on. If you negate "undertake," it denies starting, accepting, committing, attempting, etc. It really is impossible to follow what you are trying to find out without examples in context.